# Rowversion IsDBNull

Tags: c#, t-sql

Why does IsDBNull return false for rowversion columns in C# regardless of its value?

Consider the T-SQL table below.

```
CREATE TABLE [Entity] (
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] ROWVERSION NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO [Entity] ([Id]) VALUES (N'E2A87489-CEB7-4460-BC30-00264538E644')
```

When executing the T-SQL query below. Note that the query intentionally joins with a non-existent record, meaning that [JoinedEntity].[RowVersion] should be NULL. However, instead of the expected NULL value, I get the following results: one row with one column containing the value `0x`.

```
SELECT [JoinedEntity].[RowVersion] FROM [Entity] LEFT JOIN [Entity] AS [JoinedEntity] ON [JoinedEntity].[Id] = N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

When executing the C# code below, the RowVersion column is marked as being a non-null value, as is evident by executing reader.IsDBNull(0).

```
var connectionString = "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=master;Integrated Security=True;";
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    using(var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [JoinedEntity].[RowVersion] FROM [Entity] LEFT JOIN [Entity] AS [JoinedEntity] ON [JoinedEntity].[Id] = N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'", sqlConnection))
    {
        using(var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var isNull = reader.IsDBNull(0);
                
                Console.WriteLine(isNull);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When executing the T-SQL below, one can clearly see the first column having a "value" of 0x, this 0x is of course what all byte arrays start with. As can be seen by the second column, applying ISNULL clearly shows that T-SQL views this column as having a NULL value.

```
SELECT [JoinedEntity].[RowVersion], ISNULL([JoinedEntity].[RowVersion], 0x12345) FROM [Entity] LEFT JOIN [Entity] AS [JoinedEntity] ON [JoinedEntity].[Id] = N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Yet, `IsDBNull` in C# returns false. And the reason it returns false is probably the same reason why calling `reader.GetValue(0)` returns an empty byte array, not null. This inconsistency means one cannot rely completely on checking `IsDBNull` before performing additional processing. In the case of a `ROWVERSION` column  you must also check the length. To me, this seems like an oversight of the C# team, the T-SQL team, or both.

Note that other byte array column types, such as varbinary(max), do not suffer from this and return an expected NULL value.

Comment: Pretty sure RowVersion type is auto populated and is read only - so it'll never be null afaik

Comment: What makes you think [JoinedEntity].[RowVersion] is ever null?

Comment: @mm8 Why wouldn't it be able to be NULL? I'm performing a LEFT JOIN where JoinedEntity does not exist, thus according to basic SQL all its columns should be NULL. What am I missing here that according to you it should not be NULL?

Comment: @bdebaere: No one else but you can be supposed to know what your actual data looks like. It seems highly unlikely that `IsDBNull` returns the wrong value though.

Comment: <sanity check>The following demonstrates that a `NULL` is expected: `declare @Foo as Table ( RV RowVersion, X Int ); insert into @Foo ( X ) values ( 7 ); select L.RV as LeftRV, R.RV as RightRV, case when L.RV is NULL then 'Null' else 'Not Null' end as LNullishness, case when R.RV is NULL then 'Null' else 'Not Null' end as RNullishness from @Foo as L left outer join @Foo as R on R.X = 9;`.</sanity check> The mystery appears to be how C#/.NET might be _helping_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/255 this is a bug in both `System.Data.SqlClient` and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

The `System.Data.SqlClient` code will not be fixed. A breaking change will be introduced in `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` which will make `IsDbNull()` return true correctly for rowversion columns. An `AppContext` switch called `LegacyRowVersionNullBehaviour` will be added allowing the old behavior.